# Must I go on a quarterly payment plan if I owe the IRS a lot?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, penalty

**Context**: I've heard from a couple people that if you owe a significant amount of taxes to the IRS (say several thousand dollars) at tax time, then the IRS will ***require*** you to start paying future taxes in quarterly amounts. Interestingly, this requirement was not mentioned when I did my taxes via TurboTax, despite owing quite a bit.

**Question**: Must I pay quarterly in the future, or is the quarterly payment plan only an option? (and FWIW, I've adjusted my W4 so this doesn't happen again).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a one-time income tax-prepayment to the US Treasury?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/57236/how-can-i-make-a-one-time-income-tax-prepayment-to-the-us-treasury)

Comment: This is a myth. See the answers on the question linked as a duplicate.

Comment: Also relevant: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48862/estimated-taxes-after-surge-in-income

Comment: I'd call it related,  not quite duplicate.

Comment: I've owed the IRS mid 5-figure amounts, and paid it. There was no stipulation or followup from the IRS about it but maybe capital gains tax is treated more favorable than wage worker's income, which would be remarkably consistent to every regulation I've seen. Of course, there is also the relativity of what is considered "a lot".

Comment: @CQM: There's also the "safe harbor" provision, where if the amount of estimated tax (and I think withholding, but don't quote me) you paid this year is at least as much as the tax you paid last year, you're ok.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement to pay estimate taxes is if you owe $1000 or more in taxes per year. Withholding from your paycheck counts towards that payment, that is why people who are W2 employees don't actually need to file quarterly estimates.

Yes, adjusting your W4 is the right way to go.